# date format in R

Tags: r, date

I have a date column in a data frame in chr format as follows:

`chr [1:1944] "20-Sep-90" "24-Feb-05" "16-Aug-65" "19-Nov-56" "28-Nov-59" "19-Apr-86"`

I want to convert to date using something like:

`strptime(x=data$dob, '%d-%b-%y')`

But I get several future dates in the result like

```
[1] "1990-09-20" "2005-02-24" "2065-08-16" "2056-11-19" "2059-11-28" "1986-04-19" "2041-04-01" "1971-01-23"
[9] "1995-11-25" "1995-11-25" "2009-02-11" "2002-09-19" "1977-10-06" "1998-03-22" "2050-03-12" "2030-03-26"
```

Is there a way to ensure I return dates that commenced in the correct century?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look (from the documentation for `%y` in `?strptime`) like there's any obvious option for changing the default century inferred from 2-digit years.

Since the objects returned by `strptime()` have class **POSIXlt**, though, it's a pretty simple matter to subtract 100 years from any dates after today (or after any other cutoff date you'd like to use).

```
# Use strptime() to create object of class POSIXlt
dd <- c("20-Sep-90", "24-Feb-05", "16-Aug-65", 
        "19-Nov-56", "28-Nov-59", "19-Apr-86")
DD <- strptime(dd, '%d-%b-%y')

# Subtract 100 years from any date after today
DD$year <- ifelse(DD > Sys.time(), DD$year-100, DD$year)
DD
[1] "1990-09-20" "2005-02-24" "1965-08-16" "1956-11-19" "1959-11-28" "1986-04-19"
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh, I used your ifelse with the year function in lubridate to do this. `data$year <- ifelse(year(data$dob) > year(Sys.time()), year(data$dob)-100 , year(data$dob))` then pasted together and reparsed with strptime.

Answer (score 2):

```
    dd <- c("20-Sep-90", "24-Feb-05", "16-Aug-65", 
        "19-Nov-56", "28-Nov-59", "19-Apr-86")
    library(lubridate)
    DD=dmy(dd)
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
strptime(data$dob, "%Y/%m/%d")
```